# Test Interceptor : Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, testing

```
 Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

       6 |
       7 | export function AxiosInterceptor(dialogueModalChargement: any) {
    >  8 |     const [isRalentisement, setRalentisement] = useState(false);
         |                                                         ^
       9 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call hooks from outside the main body of a functional component. You CAN call them from within functions, so long as that function is called in the main body of the functional component.

You didn't share where this function is being called, so I can't say for sure what you're doing wrong. But it's almost always 1 of 2 mistakes.

#1 Using a hook in a function which is called outside of the body of a functional component.

```
function myFunc() {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
}

myFunc(); // ERROR!

const MyComponent = () => <div>Hello</div>;
```

#2 Using a hook inside the callback for another hook.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   function myFunc() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      myFunc() // ERROR!
   }, []);
}
```